# How to access instance variables from one class to another

Tags: ruby, oop, instance-variables

I am in the process of creating a simple Rock, Paper, Scissor OOP game in ruby to gain a better understanding of how everything works for Ruby OOP. But I am running into a problem.

I want to access an instance variable from another class but I am receiving this error when running the program

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from rps.rb:44:in `<main>'
    1: from rps.rb:40:in `start'
rps.rb:17:in `greeting': undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Line 17 is

```
puts "Welcome #{@player1.name} and #{@player2.name}"
```

This is my all of my code thus far

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :name, :player1, :player2,

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @player1 = Player.new(name1)
    @player2 = Player.new(name2)
  end
end

class Main

  def greeting
    puts "Welcome to Rock-Paper-Scissor"
    sleep(0.5)
    puts "Welcome #{@player1.name} and #{@player2.name}"

  end 

  def instruct
    puts "The rules of the game are simple\n"
    puts "Choose Rock, Paper or Scissor each turn\n "
    puts "Paper beats Rock, Scissor beats paper and Rock beats Scissor\n"
    puts "Ready....?"
  end

end

def start
  puts "Hi, please enter your name player 1: "
  name1 = gets.chomp
  puts "Hi, please enter your name player 2: "
  name2 = gets.chomp

  game = Main.new
  game.greeting
  game.instruct
end

start
```

*****New changes made to code for it to run properly*******

```
class Player
    attr_accessor :name

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end

end

class Game
    def greeting
        puts "Hi, please enter your name player 1: "
        name1 = gets.chomp
        @player1 = Player.new(name1)
        puts "Hi, please enter your name player 2: "
        name2 = gets.chomp
        @player2 = Player.new(name2)
        puts "Welcome to Rock-Paper-Scissor"
        sleep(0.5)
        puts "Welcome #{@player1.name} and #{@player2.name}"

    end 

    def instruct
        puts "The rules of the game are simple\n"
        puts "Choose Rock, Paper or Scissor each turn\n "
        puts "Paper beats Rock, Scissor beats paper and Rock beats Scissor\n"
        puts "Ready....?"
    end


end

def start
    game = Game.new
    game.greeting
    game.instruct

end 
start
```

Comment: Shouldn't `player1` and `player2` be in `Main`? A player is a `Player` but shouldn't contain the two players.

Comment: If a `Player` object has 2 player attributes, then those players have each 2 players, too, and those another 2. In other words you need an infinite number of players to create a single player. You should re think your structure a bit. What you probably want is a `Game` object/class that has 2 players. The `Main` class name is too generic imo

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand why my class `Player` shouldn't contain the two players. What would I put in the player class then?

Comment: The `Player` class should hold attributes of a single player only - in this case, just `name`. You can track the list of players (`@player1`, `@player2`, etc) from the `Main` class

Comment: okay I understand that now. Thanks for clearing that up. I made changes to the code  to make it work now. i'll edit above. But i do have another question, instead of putting the variable `name1` and `name2` in my `greetings` in `Game` would there have been a way for me to put that variable in my method `start` without throwing an `undefined local variable or method method for name1` error?

Comment: @nimpa : Your problem is not related to instance variable access, but to the existence of methods, since `name` is a method, not a variable. To answer your question: The error message means that either `player1` or `player2` is **not** of class `Player` and hence does not have a method called `name`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```
def greeting
  ...
  return name1, name2
end

def start
    game = Game.new
    name1,name2=game.greeting
    game.instruct
end
```